# Is there a formula that can differentiate between these duplicate values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there an excel formula that can look up the duplicate numbers in Column A and give the desired results in Column C? So if there is a unique value then it would just add "_P" at the end of it. If there are 2 similar values, then it would return "_P" for the first one and "_P1" for the 2nd one. If there are 3 similar values then it would return "_P" for the first one, "_P1" for the 2nd one and "_P2" for the 3rd one.

[image]

I tried IF, countif and concat functions but not getting the exactly desired results

Comment: Well, if you gave us data to copy then some on here would be testing already.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using <kbd>COUNTIF( )</kbd> & <kbd>IF( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,A2&"_P",A2&"_P"&COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)-1)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2),
     b,A2&"_P",
     IF(a=1,b,b&a-1))
```

---

Or, as mentioned by **[Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611989/rory)** Sir, using <kbd>TEXT()</kbd> function to suppress the `0s`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=A2&"_P"&TEXT(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)-1,"#;;")
```

---

Or, if you like to #Spill! using <kbd>MAP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=MAP(A2:A8,LAMBDA(m,LET(n,A2,m&"_P"&TEXT(COUNTIF(n:m,m)-1,"#;;"))))
```

---

Comment: Have just finished doing exactly the same function :) plus 1 for posting first.

Comment: Ah @SolarMike Sir extremely sorry for that.

Comment: I'd recommend LET to avoid doing the COUNTIF twice (or use TEXT to suppress the 0 display if LET is not available)

Comment: =IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,A2&"_P",A2&"_P"&COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)-1)

This one works perfect but one question. How comes the range in countif is A2:A2?

Comment: The range is `A$2:A2` there is a relative absolute reference. Which gives us the rolling count or running count.

Comment: As you drag down it goes from A$2:A2 to  A$2:A3, then A$2:A4 etc etc All  you need to do is check each cell and see.

Comment: @IlyasEsa ensure to accept the answer so it benefits others in the future for a similar post by checking the tick mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,A2&"_P",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=2,A2&"_P1",A2&"_P"&(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))

Place the formula in cell C2 and drag downwards

Comment: Chek out the other answer to see how you can reduce this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).